# IIS Self-signed certificate trouble - 'The Parameter is incorrect'

Tags: windows, iis-7, ca

I am trying to create a self-signed certificate in IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008, but I  get the error, 'The parameter is incorrect'. I can't find any other information about this error, does anyone know what the problem is, or where I can look to to find more information about what is going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I experienced the same issue this morning, this is caused by this year being a leap year and today the 29<sup>th</sup> of February. Set your system time back to yesterday and you will be able to create the cert.

Comment: Microsoft is aware of this issue but as of 2016 it still exists: *"Thanks for reporting the bug. This issue pertains to creation of SSL certificates by the System Center 2012 VMM server for a variety of tasks such as installation, adding a host, adding a library and deploying services. We understand the issue and are investigating further. This issue is related to the leap year date of 2/29 and will not impact operations hereafter."* 
- DeWitt Hurst [MSFT]Microsoft (MSFT) /via https://goo.gl/GmfveQ